# Difference between comparing string length and string value

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, console-application

```
namespace ProgrammingTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input");

            string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input1 == "4")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are a winnere");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (input1.Length < 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOOOOO high");

            }
            else if (input1.Length > 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOOOO Low");
                                Console.ReadLine();
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

If I input a number less than 4, why does the program not output "too low".

Comment: Type `12345` to see `Tooo Low`

Comment: Are you trying to test the length of the entered string, or the numeric value of an entered number?

Comment: What do you want to do? less than 4 symbols or less than input 4?

Comment: surely according to your code it would show tooo high? <4 is toooo high according to your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not comparing the value you are comparing the length of the input. You'll also need to convert the input from a string to an integer. For example:

```
if (int.Parse(input1) < 4) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: For console applications I find it better to use `TryParse` with `while` loop. So user input is validated properly and in a user-friendly way.

Comment: @PLB Of course I tend to use `TryParse` also, this was just meant as a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

input1 is a string.

input1.Length is the length of the string.

You want to convert the string to a numeric value before comparing.

You also need to look at your less than and greater than direction.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input");

string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
int number;
bool valid = int.TryParse(out number);

if (! valid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered value is not a number");
}
else
{

    if (number == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You are a winnere");
    }
    else if (number > 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TOOOOO high");
    }
    else if (number < 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TOOOO Low");
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```